# Custom naming conventions in Fluent NHibernate AutoMapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, naming-conventions

according to this [Post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200809205154/http://geekswithblogs.net/leesblog/archive/2008/09/02/overriding-the-default-conventions-in-fluent-nhibernate.aspx) it is possible to change the naming convention from "[TableName]_id" to "[TableName]ID". However when I saw the code, I wasn't able to do it with my rather new (about 6 weeks old) version of Fluent NHibernate.

Original code:

```
var cfg = new Configuration().Configure();
var persistenceModel = new PersistenceModel();
persistenceModel.addMappingsFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("Examinetics.NHibernate.Data"));
persistenceModel.Conventions.GetForeignKeyNameOfParent = type => type.Name + "ID";
persistenceModel.Configure(cfg);
factory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

I came up with this:

```
PersistenceModel model = new PersistenceModel();
model.AddMappingsFromAssembly(assemblyType.Assembly);
model.ConventionFinder.Add(
    ConventionBuilder.Reference.Always(part
        => part.ColumnName(part.EntityType.Name + part.Property.Name)));

configuration.ExposeConfiguration(model.Configure);
return configuration.BuildConfiguration();
```

but this gives me the original Table, because EntityType is not the referenced Entity and I see no property to get the "parent" entity.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

See [The answer about removing underscores in Ids using Fluent NHibernate Automapping conventions here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21728431/878612)

A portion of the text, the tables and classes are in the link.

### **Solution:**

Add a convention, it can be system wide, or more restricted.

```
ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id")
```

**Code example:**

```
var cfg = new StoreConfiguration();
var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(/* database config */)
  .Mappings(m =>
    m.AutoMappings.Add(
      AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Product>(cfg)
          .Conventions.Setup(c =>
              {
                  c.Add(ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id"));
              }
    )
  .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Now it will automap the `ShelfId` column to the `Shelf` property in `Product`.

---